# SSIS - Control error logs sent to SSIS catalog

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis, etl

I have a package in SSIS that has a foreach loop container that retries a specific data flow 3 times after failure.

[image]

Every failure is logged in SSIS catalog but in this case I only want to log the error when it fails for the 3rd time. Is it possible to control this error log specifically in SSIS?

I have this package being called by a master package and the final status of the execution is "failed" whenever there is at least one failure in the child package. In reality, I only want it show "failed" in the master and/or the child package when the foreach fails the 3rd time.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an execute SQL task to count the number of errors, place the count in a variable. Then use the variable connecting to the next step to check if the variable has a values of 3 or higher.

Comment: The error would always pass through regarding of variables. I do not get your point!

Comment: change the package to only pass through to the log error when the condition is value of var >=3. Please see this for a detailed description on how to do it: http://radacad.com/implement-if-condition-in-ssis-package

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these steps:

1. First, set the `ForceExecutionResult` of the Foreach loop container *(in the properties tab)* to `Success`.
2. Then, you should add a variable of type `Int` *(example: `@[User::counter]` with an initial value equal to `0`
3. Add an [Expression Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/expression-task?view=sql-server-2017) after the `Data flow Task` - with a **Failure** precedence constraint - with the following expression:

   ```
   @[User::counter] = @[User::counter] + 1
   ```
4. Add a Script Task after the Foreach loop container, inside the script check if `@[User::counter]` is equal to `3` if so, Throw an exception or use `Dts.Events.FireError()` method.

Comment: The For loop container is not the issue. Because even without forcing the execution result to success, it always behaves like that. The for loop container never fails because I have set the event handler of the data flow not to propagate on error. Therefore, even if the data flow component fails, the for each container does not fail and the error of the data flow is still logged on ssis.